# Google Chrome scroll problem — the screen splits into three parts

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

When I scroll through PDFs, and certain web pages, and I scroll using my mouse wheel.

When I scroll using the slider bar or the mouse wheel, the screen splits into 3 parts:  Upper, middle and lower.  When I scroll up, it looks like this:

[image]

When I scroll down, like this:

[image]

Together, they look like this:

[image]

Chrome version: 13.0.782.109 beta-m

Comment: Did you try reinstalling the PDF reader?

Comment: It isn't just a problem with PDFs.  I also have a problem with other pages such as [this site](http://greatneck.k12.ny.us/) it looks like ![this][1]

  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/DXSVh.png

Comment: Is it unique to Chrome? What happens if you open the same PDF in a local application, or scroll through a large Word doc, or if you use another browser on the same page?

Comment: Scroll the page out of view, then back in. Does it look okay then?

Comment: @syntech inc Out of view? what do you mean?

Comment: It's beta, it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Chrome... Everything works now...